# Coloring Piece of Tabbar

Tags: colorscheme

I am using neovim with the gruvbox colorscheme. On its github page, you can see the `buffers` word on the top right is colored in orange: 
[image]

On my installation, it grey/brown:
[image: tabbar]

- How can I find out what that object is?
- Once I know what it is, how can I color it?